# Is material just the images applying to geomtric object

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics

From graphics view, is material just the the images applying to geometric object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define **material** as **a set of data which describes how a surface reacts to light**.

---

In the [Phong-Blinn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) shading model, the material is defined by several sets of data:

- (rgb) **ambient** - *(see below)*
- (rgb) **diffuse** - how strongly it diffuses the incoming light of a given color
- (rgb) **specular** - how well it **reflects** the incoming light of a given color
- (number) shininess - how perfect (how small and focused) is the reflection. Bigger value = smaller "shining spot".

The ambient value is just added to the final color - it is there to emulate "secondary light reflections". It's usually set to the same hue as diffuse, but usually of smaller intensity.

---

By **balancing ambient/diffuse/specular/shininess parameters**, you may make the surface resemble different real-world materials.

Also, those parameters may be defined either **per-vertex** or **per-pixel** *(as a texture)*. It is common to take the values of ambient and diffuse from a colourful texture and specify constant specular and shininess, but you also could have 3 different textures for ambient, diffuse and specular colours - in order to simulate a sophisticated material which reflects the light in different way depending on the position.

There might be more parameters involved depending on what effects you want to use, for example an additional value for glowing surfaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Material usually refers to the colour of the geometric object, while the image is the texture. The material will specify how the object reacts to ambient and direct lighting, it's reflectance, transparency etc.

They can be combined in various ways to produce different effects.

For example the texture might completely override the material so that the underlying colour has no effect on the final scene.

In other cases the texture might be blended with the material so that the same texture effect can be applied to different objects (red car, blue car etc.).